# Get Firebase data and put into array using Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get firebase's data and put all the data into a String array?
Here is the code that I just write it in without calling database. But in fact I want to call firebase data and put it inside if any user add any new phone into database. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you..

```
package com.example.user8.appp3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context c;

//I wish to put all firebase's data into these array
String[] names = {"Samsung","Huawei","XIaomi","Apple","Oppo","Vivo"};
String[] price = {"100","200","300","400","500","600"};
int[] images = {R.drawable.samsung,R.drawable.huawei,R.drawable.xiaomi,R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.oppo,R.drawable.vivo};

public CustomAdapter (Context ctx)
{
    this.c = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return names[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile,null);
    }

    TextView nametxt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView pricetxt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgmobile);

    nametxt.setText(names[position]);
    pricetxt.setText(price[position]);
    img.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use Firebase as the data for the model, and have the views built from that, instead of pulling in Firebase data into local String arrays?

Comment: I want to put firebase data into the array and view in the list view. Can I do that?

Comment: Probably, but this is really suited for a Firebase tutorial. SO is a terrible tutorial site, so you are not going to get much traction here. Write some code to populate your fields from Firebase and see what happens. If you run into a specific problem feel free to research that here, and raise it as a new question.